# Integration of asymptotic Bessel function of first kind

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I have the following integral,
$$\int_{-1}^{1}dx \int_{-1}^{1}d\mu J_{n}(\beta\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}})$$
where $\beta\gg 1$.

and I naively used the asymptotic form of the Bessel function,

$$J_{n}(\beta\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}})\approx\frac{{2^{1/3} }}{{n^{1/3} }} \operatorname{Ai} \left( {\frac{{2^{1/3} (n - \beta\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}} )}}{{n^{1/3} }}} \right)$$
and then tried to evaluate the integral.

Is this the correct way to proceed ?

Comment: Is the desired quantity written correctly? It seems weirdly written to me.

Comment: Sorry there was a typo. Thank you very much for pointing it.

Comment: And your asymptotic is for large argument? If so then this will have issues in a narrow strip near the boundary, when $1-x^2$ and/or $1-\mu^2$ becomes of the order of $\beta^{-2}$. You may get the right leading order behavior anyway, though.

Comment: Thank you @Ian for the comment. Can you please elaborate about the issue. $x$ and $\mu$ can only take values from $-1$ to $1$ and the value of $\beta$ is always $\gg 1$.

Comment: Whether you care about this distinction depends on the asymptotic order that you want to expand to and the size of the next correction term.

Comment: That approximation is valid only in the transition region.

Comment: Does that mean the integration using the asymptotic form will give incorrect result ?

Comment: And if I write the integral in the following form will that be valid,  $$\int_{-1}^{1}dx \int_{-1}^{1}d\mu J_{n}(\beta\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}}) \approx \int_{-1}^{1}dx \int_{-1}^{1}d\mu \frac{{2^{1/3} }}{{n^{1/3} }} \operatorname{Ai} \left( {\frac{{2^{1/3} (n - \beta\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}} )}}{{n^{1/3} }}} \right) f(n,\beta\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}},\Gamma)$$, where $f$ is a function which peaks and becomes $1$ when $n=\beta\sqrt{1-x^{2}}\sqrt{1-\mu^{2}}$ and has a spread $\Gamma$.